# BIO-Perl Error when running the first program

Tags: perl, bioperl

I tried to run bio perl using Eclipse.

The code I tried to execute is:

```
use Bio::Seq;
$seq_obj = BIO::Seq->new(-seq=> "atcgatgcatgcatgcatgc", -alphabet=> 'dna');
#print $seq_obj->seq;
```

And I got the following error:

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "BIO::Seq" (perhaps you forgot to load "BIO::Seq"?) at C:/2ndSemester/BIO424-DevelopBioinformaticTools/PerlPrograms/BIOPerlExamples/TestBIOPerl1.pl line 3.

Anybody knows why this error occured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is called [`Bio::Seq`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bio%3a%3aSeq), not `BIO::Seq`. Perl is case sensitive so you want to say:

```
$seq_obj = Bio::Seq->new(-seq=> "atcgatgcatgcatgcatgc", -alphabet=> 'dna');
```

Note the "Bio" rather than "BIO".

Comment: Thank you very much...It worked..I am new to this BIO-Perl. Your help is much appreciated. God Bless